# Match .jpg Regex

Tags: python, regex

Pythonuser here.
I got a string with text, lets say:

```
text = "test1.jpg, test2.jpg testest.gif tata.jpg, trol.jpg, dam.blog"
```

I want to get a list with all jpg images, so I wanna match: "NAME.jpg"

My code (python3):

```
text="test1.jpg, test2.jpg testest.gif tata.jpg, trol.jpg, dam.blog"


jpgRegex = re.compile(r".+\.jpg")
list1 = jpgRegex.findall(text)
print(list1)
```

The result is not what I wanted:

```
['test1.jpg, test2.jpg testest.gif tata.jpg, trol.jpg']
```

I just dont see the problem now :( Who can help? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that `.` matches any character (but a newline in this case). If the file names do not contain space, use a non-whitespace class `\S`

Answer (score 1):

`.` matches any characters (greedily, matches as much as possible). You need to use some other pattern , for example `\S` to match only non-space characters:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "test1.jpg, test2.jpg testest.gif tata.jpg, trol.jpg, dam.blog"
>>> re.findall(r"\S+\.jpg", text)
['test1.jpg', 'test2.jpg', 'tata.jpg', 'trol.jpg']
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression will return the jpg files from your example:

```
\b[\w\-]+\.jpg\b
```

- `\b` word boundary
- `[\w\-]+` at least one word character or hyphen
- `\.` literal dot
- `jpg` literal `jpg`
- `\b` word boundary

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/sC8bD7/2)

Comment: what for `abc-def.jpg`?Its valid name but your will return `def.jpg`

Comment: @rock321987 thanks for the suggestion, I have improved my answer to handle filenames with hyphens correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `\w` instead of `.` :

```
import re                                                                        
text="test1.jpg, test2.jpg testest.gif tata.jpg, trol.jpg, dam.blog"                     
jpgRegex = re.compile(r"\w+\.jpg")                                               
list1 = jpgRegex.findall(text)                                                   
print(list1)   
>>> ['test1.jpg', 'test2.jpg', 'tata.jpg', 'trol.jpg']
```

Comment: what for `abc-def.jpg`?Its valid name but your will return `def.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "test1.jpg, test2.jpg, testest.gif, tata.jpg, trol.jpg, dam.blog"
>>> jpgRegex = re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*.jpg")
>>> list1 = jpgRegex.findall(text)
>>> list1
['test1.jpg', 'test2.jpg', 'tata.jpg', 'trol.jpg']
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good case for using [`fnmatch.fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch):

```
>>> from fnmatch import fnmatch
>>> [x.rstrip(',') for x in text.split() if fnmatch(x.rstrip(','), '*.jpg')]
['test1.jpg', 'test2.jpg', 'tata.jpg', 'trol.jpg']
```

Or using built-in method, `str.endswith()`:

```
>>> [x.rstrip(',') for x in text.split() if x.rstrip(',').endswith('.jpg')]
['test1.jpg', 'test2.jpg', 'tata.jpg', 'trol.jpg']
```